# Adding item to ember-data store prevents application template from rendering

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-rails

I have a following route definition in my ember-rails project. 
The file is /app/assets/javascripts/routes/applicationRoute.js.coffee and the code is as follows:

```
ChAdmin.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend (
   model: ()->
     store = @.get("store")
     store.push("tapahtuma",
       id: 1,
       nimi: "test1",
       paiva: "11.1.2012"
     )

)
```

This prevents the application template from rendering. Can anyone tell me why is that?
I can see from embers inspector that the item has been pushed to store.
If I do anything else except push items in the store the app template renders just fine.

There are no errors in javascript console and starting the app I get:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.10.2 ember.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js?body=1:394
Ember Debugger Active
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was an old version of ember-data. 
I ran "rails generate ember:install --head" and now the application template renders correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the model from `model()`

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    var store = this.get('store');
    store.push("tapahtuma",
      {
         id: 1,
         nimi: "test1",
         paiva: "11.1.2012"
      }
     );
    // model is expected to return the object or 
    // a promise that resolve into the object
    return store.find('tapahtuma',1); 
  }
});
```

More details on the `model()` hook in the [emberjs guide on routing](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/).

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1321/edit)

Comment: Adding return only makes model data render. As you can see from your JSBin example, if you remove  the return statement application template still renders. You put me on the right track though. Since your example used a newer version of ember-data, I updated my ember & ember-data versions and now the app template renders correctly.